# Conditional Variance of a Random Variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Say I have the following random variable:

[image]

Where $\varphi_{i}$ and $\rho_{j}$ are themselves independent random variables (note: given particular values for $\varphi_{i}$ and $\rho_{j}$, $Q_{ij}$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $\varphi_{i}\rho_{j}$). Find,

[image]

Here is what I have (I used the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)):

[image]

Is my reasoning correct? For some reason I am not confident in it?

Comment: I dont see any problem with your calculations. Why are you not confident?

Comment: Seyhmus, thanks for the feedback. I was not confident because originally, I had done this: http://i.imgur.com/Uh5PkmD.png (which is definitely flawed)

Comment: I see for this version of the solution I dont see a mistake.

Comment: Thanks Seyhmus, I am more confident know in the answer